# knockoutjs if binding problems

Tags: javascript, if-statement, knockout.js, data-binding

The if binding doesn't seem to be working for me. Here is my template:

```
<div>
    <span data-bind="text: name"></span> 
    <div data-bind="if: false ">+<span data-bind="text: priceFormatted"></span></div>
</div>
```

The `if: false` is there as a smoketest, because no matter what I put there, the span always shows up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It breaks using v1.1.2, but works just fine in v2.0.  See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QLzQ6/).  Maybe you need to use the later version of Knockout.JS?

Comment: Yep, the docs got updated by my version of ko didn't. Guess I should subscribe to their blog or something.

Comment: If you use NuGet in Visual Studio 2010 to add references like KO, it will notify you when a new version is available. (if you are using VS2012)

Answer (score 0):

I tried  you're example and it's working fine for me.

Do you have your script references at the bottom of your page to make sure the entire DOM has loaded?

For example, here is one of my files:

```
    <html>
        <head>

        </head>

        <body>

            <div class="container">

               <!-- PUT CONTENT HERE -->

            <div>


            <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/knockout-2.0.0.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/custom.js"></script>


        </body>
   </html>
```